# how to solve sql (case when),(in)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

it is error like

> Incorrect syntax near ','

when i choose to use case when statement, plz help me thanks!!!!

**if statement:**

```
declare @module nvarchar(max)='tenant'
if (@module='tenancy')
select 'All'
UNION 
select distinct affect_table from sys_log where affect_table in ('contract','rent_free','dn_override')
```

**case when statement:**

```
select 'All'
UNION 
select distinct affect_table from sys_log where affect_table in (case when @module='tenant' THEN ('contract','rent_free','dn_override'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like you need `CASE`, just simple logic:

```
select distinct affect_table from sys_log
where
   (affect_table in ('contract','rent_free','dn_override')
    and
    @module = 'tenant')
```

As to why your attempt doesn't work, that's because `CASE` is an *expression* - it has to return a scalar value. Not a set of values. Nor a list. Or whatever else you'd decided `('contract','rent_free','dn_override')`, in and of itself, was meant to be an instance of.